# Firestore/Firebase id String ordering

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Where can I find the ordering of chars used for comparing strings in firebase/firestore?

When I was greating ids to be ordered
I noticed: 2!, 2), 2@, 2A, 2_A, 2a was the ascending order and I'm wondering where I can find a reference so I know what char/string comparisons will give what results

I'm tagging the post with json because I know firebase RTD was json but I'm not sure about firestore

Comment: String follow lexicographical ordering using Unicode character set. So same as before essentially.